# Can not revert from "open as source code" in Stoaryboard Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have opened Storyboard as source code to inspect a component. Now can't go back. After right click it shows "none" option. [image: options shown after right click]

Comment: You might have corrupted the XML accidentally. Restore from back up or version control

Comment: @Paulw11 I did not change anything. It would have shown an error message if that is the case.